# user session tracking in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an app in phonegap (pure js, html, css) where user signs in and then it has access to some aditional sites. My question is how to save his personal data or his session. There is no php involved for sending cookie or handling sessions. Everything need to be saved in JS (jQuery). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HTML5` feature Local Storage

For eg;

When user logs in, set one variable as `isAuthenticated` in your local storage

By default, it will be 0, on successful login, set it to 1.

```
localStorage.isAuthenticated = 0; // default
OR
localStorage.setItem('isAuthenticated',0);
```

On Successful login

```
localStorage.isAuthenticated = 1; // default
OR
localStorage.setItem('isAuthenticated',1);
```

And whenever you want to check user's authenticity, simply compare value of `isAuthenticated` variable from Local Storage.

var isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated');

```
if(isLoggedIn){
    //your code
} else {
    // invalid user code
}
```

UPDATE
If you are storing javascript objects then

```
var myObject = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 };

// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('myObject', JSON.stringify(myObject));

// Retrieve the object from storage
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('myObject');
retrievedObject = JSON.parse(retrievedObject)
```

Convert your object into `string` using `JSON.stringify` and then store it into the local storage.
While retrieving `cast` that `string` back into the `javascript object` using `JSON.parse`

Looking at the local storage documentation, the functionality seems to be limited to handle only string key/value pairs.

You can take a look at the documentation here

[Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Name-ValueStorage/Name-ValueStorage.html)

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage)

PS : Phonegap has nothing to do with working of local storage or any other HTML feature. Phonegap is just a middleware that facilitates communication between your device hardware and your javascript/html code.

Comment: I already saw that solution but it doesnt work with phonegap. Dont know really why

Comment: It works... I am using the same thing with phonegap...
Just a doubt, are you storing javascript objects?

Comment: haha :).. No it doesn't... You can always get a workaround for that though... Check the updated answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the PhoneGap documentation on LocalStorage and SQL Database:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage

Comment: But if I write in local storage it will stay there when the user close the app (well I'll have to erase it by myself, but I would like to be erased automaticly)